# variance of maximum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $(X_i)_{i\leq n}$ be random variables, which may be dependent. Is it true that
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{Var}(\max X_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i).
> \end{align*}

I have tried integrating the tail probability,
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(\max X_i) &= E\left( \max X_i - E \max X_i \right)^2 \\
&= \int_0^\infty P\left((\max X_i - E \max X_j)^2 > t \right) dt \\
&\leq \int_0^\infty P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{(X_i - E \max X_j)^2 > t\} \right) dt \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^\infty P((X_i-E \max X_j)^2 > t) dt \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n E (X_i - E \max X_j)^2,
\end{align*}
but this is not quite what we need. It seems that if the $X_i$ are independent, then I shouldn't have lost anything in the union bound. Does anyone know of a counter example or a proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution looks good. One can get the same bound using the [Efron-Stein inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality#Efron%E2%80%93Stein_inequality).
Using the notation in your answer,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(\max_i X_i)
&\le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n E[(\max_i X_i - \max\{X_1,\ldots, X_{k-1}, Y_k, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n\})^2]
\\ &\le \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n E[(X_k - Y_k)^2].
\end{align}
To justify the last inequality, note that

- if
  $\max_i X_i > \max\{X_1,\ldots, X_{k-1}, Y_k, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n\}$
  then $k = i^*$ (where $X_{i^*} = \max_i X_i$) and thus $X_k = \max_i X_i > \max\{X_1,\ldots, X_{k-1}, Y_k, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n\} \ge Y_k$
- if $\max_i X_i < \max\{X_1,\ldots, X_{k-1}, Y_k, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n\}$ then $Y_k = \max\{X_1,\ldots, X_{k-1}, Y_k, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n\} \ge \max_i X_i \ge X_k$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the trick. Let $(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$ be an independent copy. Then
\begin{align*}
2\text{Var}(\max X_i) = E(\max X_i - \max Y_i)^2 = \int_0^\infty P((\max X_i - \max Y_i)^2>t)dt.
\end{align*}
If $X_{i^*} = \max X_i$ and $Y_{j^*} = \max Y_j$, then since $Y_{j^*} \geq Y_{i^*}$ and $X_{i^*} \geq X_{j^*}$, we have that $|X_{i^*}-Y_{j^*}| > \sqrt{t}$ implies  either
\begin{align*}
X_{i^*}-Y_{i^*}>\sqrt{t} \hspace{1em}\text{ or } \hspace{1em}Y_{j^*}-X_{j^*} > \sqrt{t}.
\end{align*}
Hence 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty P((\max X_i - \max Y_i)^2 > t) dt &\leq \int_0^\infty P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{(X_i - Y_i)^2 > t\}\right) dt \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^\infty P((X_i-Y_i)^2>t)dt \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i-Y_i)^2 \\
&= 2\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i).
\end{align*}